# Exception when fetching parse.com user data in iOS 8 Today Extension

Tags: ios, iphone, parse-platform, ios-app-extension, ios8-today-widget

I am trying to fetch a list of PFObjects of a PFUser to display in the iOS 8 Today Widget.

Following this [blog post](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/introducing-local-data-sharing-for-apple-watch-and-app-extensions/) by Parse, I've enabled the same App Groups and Keychain Sharing in both my main app and extension in Xcode.

I've also enabled the following in the `AppDelegate` of my main app and the `viewDidLoad` of my Today Extension:

```
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
[Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.me.myapp" containingApplication:@"com.me.myapp"];
[Parse setApplicationId:@"myAppId" clientKey:@"myClientId"];
```

In `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`, I constructed and performed my query:

```
- (void) widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NCUpdateResult))completionHandler {
      PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Note"];
      [query whereKey:@"User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

      [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
         if (!error)
         {
            // check for difference between current and new data
            if([self hasNewData:objects]) {
                // fresh data
                notes = objects;
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                [self updatePreferredContentSize];
                completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNewData);
            } else {
                // Data is the same
                completionHandler(NCUpdateResultNoData);
            }
         } else {
            // Failed
            completionHandler(NCUpdateResultFailed);
         }
      }];
    }
}
```

The first load seems to work fine - I'm able to get my list of PFObjects. However, whenever the extension reloads a second time, the following exception: `enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:containingApplication:' must be called before 'setApplicationId:clientKey''` is thrown at the `enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier` call in `viewDidLoad`.

I can replicate this reload by swiping the Notification Center to the "Notifications" tab and swiping it back, which would cause viewDidLoad to be invoked again.

I've double-checked that the order of calling the methods are right, and even tinkered with the order but am still getting the crash.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if(![Parse isLocalDatastoreEnabled]) {
    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
    [Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.me.myapp" containingApplication:@"com.me.myapp"];
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"myAppId" clientKey:@"myClientId"];
}
```

Comment: Making sure Parse initializes only once within the extension mitigates the crash. However, the state of [PFUser currentUser] now remains unchanged when I log in or out of the main application.

Comment: Could you provide your code, where you are using PFUser?

Comment: I'm accessing [PFUser currentUser] right after the initialization steps above, in the viewDidLoad of my extension.

Comment: Are you getting PFUser from LocalDatastore in your extension? Have you changing pinned PFUser on logout\login in your main app?

Comment: No, I am not retrieving the PFUser from my local datastore. According to the docs at https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#extensions-shared-local-data, the current PFUser should be persisted across apps so I was expecting the syncing to be seamless, without any form of manual pinning or retrieving. Neither have i changed the pinned PFUser upon logging in and out of my app.

Comment: You Sir, just made my day, this issue was driving me crazy!

Comment: Wowowowo Thanks man! I was suffering a lot with this stupid bug.