# State of [PFUser currentUser] not persisted across main application and iOS Today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, ios8-today-widget, ios-extensions

I've enabled local data sharing between my Parse application and iOS Today Extension following the official documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#extensions-shared-local-data), making the necessary initialization calls in both the `AppDelegate` of my app and the `viewDidLoad` method of my extension, with the right key chains and app groups.

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`:

```
[Parse enableLocalDatastore];
[Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.my.app"];
[Parse setApplicationId:@"appId" clientKey:@"clientKey"];
```

In the `viewDidLoad` method of my extension:

```
// Ensure Parse is only initialized once, otherwise an exception will be thrown
if(![Parse isLocalDatastoreEnabled]) {
    [Parse enableDataSharingWithApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.com.my.app"
                                 containingApplication:@"com.my.app"];
    [Parse enableLocalDatastore];
    // Setup Parse
    [Parse setApplicationId:@"appId"
            clientKey:@"clientKey"];
}
```

I could make queries in my extension, but I notice that if I start off in a logged state, go to my app and issue a logout, `[PFUser currentUser]` remains non-nil in the extension (I can still access the information in the currentUser). Conversely, if I start off in a logged out state, go to the app, login and switch to my extension, `[PFUser currentUser]` remains nil.

Any ideas on why changes in the logon status of the `PFUser` are not synced across the app and its extensions?

If I had disabled `isLocalDatastoreEnabled` check, the widget would [crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30846723/exception-when-fetching-parse-com-user-data-in-ios-8-today-extension) on every second subsequent invocation, but when it is reloaded, at least the state of the `currentUser` will be in sync, so this is all very puzzling.

Comment: Did you solve this? Same issue here...

Comment: Same here, any ideas?